# Cannot get adjusted means for glmer using lsmeans

Tags: r, lme4, lsmeans

I have a glm that I would like to get adjusted means for using lsmeans. The following code makes the model (and seems to be doing it correctly):

```
library(lmerTest)
data$group <- as.factor(data$grp)
data$site <- as.factor(data$site)
data$stimulus <- as.factor(data$stimulus)

data.acc1 = glmer(accuracy ~ site + grp*stimulus + (1|ID), data=data, family=binomial)
```

However, using when I try to use any of the below code to get adjusted means for the model, I get the error

> Error in lsmeansLT(model, test.effs = test.effs, ddf = ddf) :
>     The model is not linear mixed effects model.

```
lsmeans(data.acc1, "stimulus")
```

or

```
data.lsm <- lsmeans(data.acc1, accuracy ~ stimulus ~ grp)
pairs(data.lsm)
```

Any suggestiongs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't get lsmeans output in glmer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752417/i-cant-get-lsmeans-output-in-glmer)

Comment: The error message comes from the **lmerTest** package. Try the **lsmeans** package instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have created a generalised linear mixed model using `glmer()` (in this case a mixed logistic regression model) not a linear mixed model using `lmer()`. The `lsmeans()` function does not accept objects created by `glmer()` because they are not linear mixed models.

Answers in this post might help: [I can't get lsmeans output in glmer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28752417/4269699)

And this post might be useful if you want to understand/compute marginal effects for mixed GLMs: [Is there a way of getting "marginal effects" from a `glmer` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24177197/4269699)